# $C$ is a companion matrix. $F[C]$ is a field extension of $F$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $F$ is a field. For a monic  polynomial $m \in F[x] $ we ‎ let $C(m)=\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}} \mathrm{E}_{(i+1)i}‎ - \displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^{n}} ‎m_{i-1} \mathrm{E}_{in} \in \mathrm{M}_n(\mathbb{F})$‎
be a companion matrix of m, where
$m(x) = m_0+m_1x+ \ldots+m_{n-1}x^{n-1}+x^n$ .   If $m$ is irreducible   $F[C]$  is a field extension of $F$. But what about  $m $ is reducible . Can any one help?

Comment: What is $F[C]$, where $C$ is a matrix?

Comment: $F[C] = \{p(C) | p \in  F[x]\}$
be the unital algebra generated by $C$.

Comment: In that case, we have $F[C(m(X))] \cong F[X]/(m(X))$.

Comment: Ok, I know that when $m$ is irreducible. but what a bout $m$ is reducible. can you tell me about it.

Comment: What I wrote applies equally to both cases, but when $m$ is reducible the ring $F[X]/(m(X))$ has zero divisors.

Comment: yes that   it is true for both case. But  I have mistak  about reducible case can you explain more please?

Comment: You haven't given any indication in the question what you're looking for, but if $m(X) = a(X)b(X)$ is a nontrivial factorization, then $a(C)$ and $b(C)$ are nonzero in $F[C]$, but $a(C)b(C) = m(C) = 0$.

Comment: I'm sorry if I confused you.  I decided  if $m$ is reducible, $F[x]/(m)$ is not even an integral domain. So $F[x]/(m)$ is not a field and  if we say $F[C]$ is a field it means $m$ is irreducible. Is it true?